# include template twig in page angular

Tags: angularjs, symfony, twig

I want to make a call to a twig template in my angular page.

```
<div ng-include="BundleName:moarTemplates:bar.html"></div>
```

can you help me

Comment: `ng-include` was in `angularJS` aka **angular 1** and you have tagged your questions with `angular` aka **angular 2+**. In which version do u want to implement this functionality ? 1 or 2 ?

Comment: i want implement this functionality in AngularJs

Answer (score 1):

i don't think you can do it because the twig template must be compiled by php to be display the page a the variable so server how do this job **Server Side** , but the angulair page its the navigateur how do this job **Client Side** and he don't have php

Answer (score 1):

Symfony  and  angular it'a a  bit  tricky thing ,  but it can be done (mostly) .

1. include symfony generated page in angular - can be done by  using FOS Js routing
   https://symfony.com/doc/current/bundles/FOSJsRoutingBundle/usage.html
2. using angular in twig - also  is possible , but you need to change "delimeters"  in angular  you can't  use " {{" and "}}" for  both twig and angular on the same  view.

One thing that you can't do in a easy way is  passing  variables(data) from twig to angular  nad  vice versa .  To pass data between sf and angular use  api that generates data as json